# How do I use the determinant of a matrix to show that some vectors are linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, independence

How do I use the determinant of a matrix to show that some vectors are linearly independent?

[image]

I found that the determinant is -3.

I know that if the determinant of a matrix is non-zero then the vectors are linearly independent.
But here we are dealing with different vectors than the vectors of the columns of the matrix.
Help, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

If the four vectors from $\mathbb{R}^7$ would be linearly *dependent*, then you can write one of them as a linear combination of the other ones. By that same linear combination, the *first four components* of these vectors would form four linearly dependent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and putting them in a $4\times 4$-matrix would result in its determinant being...?

Comment: How do we prove that the independence of the 4 vectors in R^7 is equivalent to the fact that there exists a selection of 4 components such that the 4x4 matrix made be taking the components of the four vectors is invertible?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Divide your vectors in the following manner

$$u_{i}=\begin{pmatrix}{}\\v^{1}_{i}\\\\ \hline\\ v^{2}_{i}\\{}\end{pmatrix}$$

Now if the $u_{i}$'s are linearly dependent, what can you say about the $v^{1}_{i}$'s?